# SwiftUI List with Textfield Binding - reorder messes up when textfield is focused

Tags: swift, xcode, list, swiftui, textfield

I have a list which represents an array with book titles.
The title is displayed by a textfield so the user can tap in and edit the title right away.

When I enable edit mode and reorder the elements, while a textfield is focused, it messes up the list rows and bindings.
I assume it's a bug as it only happens when moving list rows upwards.

Edit:

- I filed a bug report to Apple. Case: FB9976702
- Does someone know a workaround?

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextfieldList: View {

    @State var books = [
        Book(name: "Lord of the Rings"),
        Book(name: "Harry Potter"),
        Book(name: "War and Peace")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach($books) { $book in
                    TextField(book.name, text: $book.name)
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        books.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }

}

struct Book: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: You should file a Feedback with Apple for this.

Comment: I just did. Case: FB9976702

Comment: in my opinion, it's better to push or present an editing view to change item's content, list editing mainly for item order & removing

Comment: Yes, thats usually also my approach but in case of the actual production app this is for, it would make much more sense this way.